# Double quotes get added when export and saving text using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have code to export my data and save it as a file, but it adding double quotes to entire text while exporting.

my code is

```js
$scope.clickExport = function() {
  var txt = 'This is sample text to export';
  var objectToExport = txt;
  var filename = response.data.fileName;
  var blob = new Blob([angular.toJson(objectToExport, true)], {
    type: 'text/text'
  });
  if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
  } else {
    var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
      a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download = filename;
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.dataset.downloadurl = ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':');
    e.initEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(e);
  }
}
```

what change I have to do in this so it should not add double quotes on export text.

Comment: Try removing the angular.toJson

Comment: thank you so much, its working :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the line

```
   var blob = new Blob([angular.toJson(objectToExport, true)], {
    type: 'text/text'
 });
```

with this

```
var blob = new Blob([objectToExport], {
    type: 'text/text'
 });
```